# Acomodar input centrados usando bootstrap

Tags: c#, bootstrap

Estoy usando bootstrap y estoy añadiendo unos select a mi pagina, quisiera que fueran de un menos tamaño y que esten uno a lado de otro de mamenra centrada,
sin embargo me sale de esta manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionarlo?

```
...
<body>

            <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
                <br>
                <label>Razon Social :</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="razon">
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
                <br>
                <label>Razon Social :</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="razon">
                </select>
            </div>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Se colocaron los `div.col-md-3` dentro de un `div.row`
2. Al div.row se le agregó la clase `justify-content-center` para centrar los select
3. Se removieron las clases `ml-auto`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>


       <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <br>
                <label>Razon Social :</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="razon">
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <br>
                <label>Razon Social :</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="razon">
                </select>
            </div>
       </div>

</body>
```